# How do I use MS Access SQL to make a not equal condition?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently want everything that is not 'Apple' or 'Banana' under column 'Fruits'.

My current code is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [MyTable].[Fruits] <> "Apple" OR [MyTable].[Fruits]<>'Banana'
;
```

Yet it still gives me Banana and Apple values. Any advice?

Comment: Change `OR` to `AND`. Btw, `Cross Currency Swap` sounds like a very tasty banana...

Comment: Just want to add that it is not a spelling error or anything silly like that. I used the '=' sign and it gave me only apple and banana values, whereas the '<>' sign is not working.

Comment: Single quotes for `'Apple'`.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the code slightly wrong. Make more sense now?

Comment: You can also do `WHERE [MyTable].[Fruits] NOT IN ('Apple', 'Banana')`.

Comment: Also, single quote or double quote doesnt change anything.

Comment: Jarlh got it, still kind of curious why my code doesnt work though.

Comment: @J.H, well, I don't know MS Access very well, but ANSI SQL (and most dbms products) have double quotes for identifiers, and single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `OR` to `AND`, otherwise `Apple` is returned because it's no `Banana` and vice versa:

```
'Apple' <> 'Banana' -> TRUE
'Apple' <> 'Apple'  -> FALSE

TRUE  OR FALSE -> TRUE   -> Apple returned
TRUE AND FALSE -> FALSE  -> Apple not returned
```

Btw, multiple `OR` on the same column translate to `Fruits IN ('Banana', 'Apple')` and multiple `AND` translate to `Fruits NOT IN ('Banana', 'Apple')`

Comment: This makes so much sense explainin this way. Thanks.